# Odd behavior in pattern matching for functional form

Tags: pattern-matching

Consider the two seemingly closely related operations:

```
DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, x_[_] /; x == f]
(* {g[x], h[x]} *)    
DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, x_[_] /; x != f]
(* {f[x], g[x], h[x]} *)
```

The first case gives the desired result of removing `f[x]`, while the second doesn't work properly (I would expect to get back only `f[x]` in that case). However, the only difference between the two is the use of a `!=` as opposed to a `==`. Is this a bug or is there a good reason for this behavior?

**Note:** Interestingly, even `Not[Equal[x,f]]` doesn't fix the problem (while `Equal[x,f]` does work).

Comment: Not sure *quite* what is going (I'm pretty sure it's relatively straight-forward), but consider doing the following: `DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, x_[_] /; (x =!= f)]`. Also, `DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, _f]` and `Cases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, _f]`.

Comment: For comparisons like yours, you really should be using `===`/`=!=` instead of `==`/`!=`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even `Equal` doesn't work, although it *seems* to work. What you expect is a comparison, that gives `True` when two symbols are the same and `False` otherwise. Look at this:

```
f == g
(* f == g *)
```

This is surely not what you expect. While it seems OK in your first example, because `f==f` indeed simplifies to `True`, the flaw becomes obvious in your second example:

```
g != f
(* g != f *)
```

*Mathematica* tries to decide whether `f` and `g` are unequal. The problem is that *unequal* is not equivalent to *they are not the same*. So the rule of thumb is, if you do numeric comparisons, then you often want to use `==` or `!=` except you are comparing exact numbers. If you want to decide whether expressions are the same or not, then you need to use `===` or `=!=`.

Here are some examples as a brain teaser:

```
1 === 1.0
(* False *)

1 == 1.0
(* True *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something "ugly" also:

```
DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, x_[_] /; TrueQ[x == f]]

(*{g[x], h[x]}*)

DeleteCases[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}, x_[_] /; !TrueQ[x == f]]

(*{f[x]}*)
```